# What techniques are used to build ray intersection acceleration structures on the GPU?

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, gpu, data-structure, bounding-volume-hierarchy

What improvements and alternatives have been developed since HLBVH was introduced in the 2010 paper [HLBVH: Hierarcihcal LBVH Construction for Real-Time Ray Tracing of Dynamic Geometry](http://research.nvidia.com/publication/hlbvh-hierarchical-lbvh-construction-real-time-ray-tracing) by J. Pantaleoni and D. Luebke?